# copy data from s3 to local with prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy data from s3 to local with prefix using aws-cli.

But I am getting error with different regex.

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/RAW_TIMESTAMP_0506* . --profile prod
```

error:

> no matches found: s3://my-bucket-name/RAW_TIMESTAMP_0506*

Comment: please mention information about "RAW_TIMESTAMP_0506" i.e. is it a file name pattern , prefix etc.

Comment: @tom Yes it is prefix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated:** Added `--recursive` and `--exclude`

The `aws s3 cp` command will not accept a wildcard as part of the filename (key). Instead, you must use the `--include` and `--exclude` parameters to define filenames.

From: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

> Currently, there is no support for the use of UNIX style wildcards in a command's path arguments. However, most commands have `--exclude "<value>"` and `--include "<value>"` parameters that can achieve the desired result. These parameters perform pattern matching to either exclude or include a particular file or object. The following pattern symbols are supported.

So, you would use something like:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://my-bucket-name/ . --exclude "*" --include "RAW_TIMESTAMP_0506*"
```

Comment: I don't think it is working without --recursive flag. I have one internal directory inside my bucket and i don't want to copy files from there. Please suggest

Comment: Correct! Either use the `--recursive` flag, so use `aws s3 sync`, which includes subdirectories.

Comment: The command doesn't work at all. Need to also have exclude because `--include` doesn't exclude by itself.

Comment: This is accepted answer? How

Comment: Updated answer to use `--recursive` and `--exclude`.

Answer (score 52):

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/ <local directory path> --recursive --exclude "*" --include "<prefix>*"
```

This will copy only files with given prefix

Comment: yes if you specify . then things will be downloaded to root, whereas specifying ./path-to-folder make things to be downloaded to particular path !! It worked thanks..

Answer (score 14):

The above answers to not work properly... for example I have many thousands of files in a directory by date, and I wish to retrieve only the files that are needed.. so I tried the correct version per the documents:

`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/sub /my/local/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "20170906*.png"`

and it did not download the prefixed files, but began to download everything

so then I tried the sample above:

`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/sub/ . /my/local --recursive --include "20170906*"`

and it also downloaded everything... It seems that this is an ongoing issue with aws cli, and they have no intention to fix it... Here are some workarounds that I found while Googling, but they are less than ideal.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1454

Comment: use --exclude "*" also along with your command above it should work.

Comment: For an S3 file with name `dev20200808.json`, I've tried :: 

`aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/ ./path-to-my-local-folder --exclude "*" --include "*20200808*" --recursive` and it worked!! For the first time I've only had `--include`, thinking only matching objects will be copied but sadly everything in the bucket has been copied, then I've used `--exclude` along with `--include` to make it work. Finally, it seems to be first `exclude` everything and then `include` what's needed :-) Also if you just give `.` instead of `./path-to-my-local-folder` then files will be copied to root folder.

Comment: A good workaround from the Git issue linked: `aws s3 ls "s3://bucket/prefix" | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I % aws s3 cp s3://bucket/% .`

Answer (score 6):

If you don't like silent consoles, you can pipe `aws ls` thru `awk` and back to `aws cp`.

**Example**

```
# url must be the entire prefix that includes folders.
# Ex.: url='s3://my-bucket-name/folderA/folderB',
# not url='s3://my-bucket-name'
url='s3://my-bucket-name/folderA/folderB'
prefix='RAW_TIMESTAMP_0506'
aws s3 ls "$url/$prefix" | awk '{system("aws s3 cp '"$url"'/"$4 " .")}'
```

**Explanation**

- The `ls` part is pretty simple. I'm using variables to simplify and shorten the command. Always wrap shell variables in double quotes to prevent disaster.
- `awk {print $4}` would extract only the filenames from the `ls` output (NOT the S3 Key! This is why url must be the entire prefix that includes folders.)
- `awk {system("echo " $4")}` would do the same thing, but it accomplishes this by calling another command. Note: I did NOT use a subshell `$(...)`, because that would run the entire `ls | awk` part *before* starting `cp`. That would be slow, and it wouldn't print anything for a looong time.
- `awk '{system("echo aws s3 cp "$4 " .")}'` would print commands that are *very close* to the ones we want. Pay attention to the spacing. If you try to run this, you'll notice something isn't quite right. This would produce commands like `aws s3 cp RAW_TIMESTAMP_05060402_whatever.log .`
- `awk '{system("echo aws s3 cp '$url'/"$4 " .")}'` is what we're looking for. This adds the path to the filename. Look closely at the quotes. Remember we wrapped the `awk` parameter in single quotes, so we have to close and reopen the quotes if we want to use a shell variable in that parameter.
- `awk '{system("aws s3 cp '"$url"'/"$4 " .")}'` is the final version. We just remove `echo` to actually *execute* the commands created by `awk`. Of course, I've also surrounded the `$url` variable with double quotes, because it's good practice.

Comment: I wasn't bothered by the quietness, but I was bothered with timeouts when the copying took a long time and the token eventually expired. I ended up doing something vaguely like this, copying a listing of the files I wanted to my laptop and then copying over them one by one in a loop with `xargs`.

Comment: @tripleee I would love to see your xargs solution!

Comment: Basically `aws s3 ls s3://path/to/prefix/ | sed 's%^%s3://path/to/prefix/' >file.txt` and then `xargs -i aws s3 cp {} . <file.txt`

Comment: This is my favorite answer for the feedback loop in terminal. Thank you!

Comment: If you are not pointing directly to the files (but to other paths in between) and want to download files recursively you should use: `aws s3 ls "$url/$prefix" | awk '{system("aws s3 cp '"$url"'/"$2 " ./"$2 " --recursive ")}'`

Comment: This answer is faster than other answers if you have thousands of hundreds of files in `$url`.